# Avoiding an horizontal scrollbar on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

Google Webmaster Tools reports that this page - https://www.shlomifish.org/__Beta-kmor/meta/FAQ/about.xhtml - has a horizontal scrollbar in mobile mode. I verified its presence using Firefox's `Ctrl-shift-m` in 360x740 portrait mode. How can I eliminate the horizontal scrollbar there?

Note that adding `main { overflow: scroll; }` is a symptomatic (and not too good) fix, and I'm seeking a better solution.

( The XHTML and CSS both validate. )

Answer (score 0):

```
main.main {
     max-width: 100vw;
}
```

or, more specific with media query:

```
@media (max-width:450px) {
  main.main {
      max-width: 100vw;
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't help - either with `100vw` or `50vw`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your `grid` display setup on your body.
On mobile change on display block and it'll works.

```
@media (max-width:650px) {
  body {
      display:block;
  }
}
```